# Are CIP services for reading and writing PLC tags (on AB Logix 5000 controllers) atomic?

Tags: plc

I'm following the Allen-Bradley documentation for controller data access using CIP, specifically the read tag service, write tag service, and details around reading/writing whole UDTs: https://literature.rockwellautomation.com/idc/groups/literature/documents/pm/1756-pm020_-en-p.pdf. I am using an EIP library to perform read/write tag services and multi-service requests.

What I want clarification on is whether reading or writing entire UDTs is an atomic operation (using the methods outlined in the manual for performing the read/write in one service request and understanding the metadata to unpack it)? I.e., is it true that the PLC or software side would never see a partially updated UDT value when successfully read/written as a whole?

A related question is: if I wanted to read/write several tags by sending multiple Read/Write tag service requests inside a multi-service request, do I have any guarantees on synchronized read/write for the set of tags? I assume not, but I can't seem to find any definitive documentation on the subject. Especially if the request gets fragmented across multiple CIP packets.

Comment: did you ever get this resolved?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I just posted an answer. My question may not have been clear, but I was more interested in whether the reads/writes appear atomic from the perspective of the PLC (i.e., PLC sees consistent data not partially updated data). The service request does succeed but I discovered it is not automatically synchronized with the PLC so if arrays/UDT need synchronization it's up to me to add a flag or mutex for that purpose. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to test this and confirm that read/write tag CIP service is not atomic for a single UDT or array. My original concern was whether I can safely write an entire UDT or an array and ensure that the PLC processing that data would see that data in its "before written" or "after written" state, rather than some partially written state. I performed some tests writing a 10-element DINT array from the CIP write tag service. On the PLC, I perform a synchronous copy (CPS) to copy the array into another tag and then I check it to see if the data is consistent with being atomically copied. I saw the data was occasionally in a partially written state, meaning the write tag service is not synchronized with the synchronous copy instruction. Note that I used a single CIP service request for writing the array, not several requests for each element. This is not totally unexpected but it is good to know so that anyone reading/writing multiple values from a CIP service is aware of the lack of synchronization. I can add my own synchronization mechanisms in cases where it is required.

Comment: Are you using a status register specific to the MSG controller? Or a timer to insure all data arrives before using any of the Array/UDT? Or??? I'm just trying to see how others skin this cat.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the MSG controller. In my case, I'm using a Java library that implements EIP services including the read/write tag services. On the PLC side, I don't have any explicit instructions in the program to receive/send the data, it's just controller-scoped tags that are updated. So in my case, I can add a "ready" flag if I need to indicate when data is fully written so I don't process it in a partially-written state.

Answer (score 1):

We typically inspect the "General Status" in the Message Response Field to determine success (completion??) or failure of CIP message. However, if its critical that the PLC receives the entire pack of data before using any of it I will add some type of timer logic to insure enough time has transpired (after initiating the message) before (confidently) using the data. Lazy? Yes. But it works.

Specific to your question regarding atomicity via read/write services. The general rule of thumb is to not rely upon any message data being atomic (especially large packets). You must wait feedback/response from the service request.

[image: From Logix 5000 Controllers Data Access document - Pg 18]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

At work we found that it was the case that any read/write of more than a DINT (we did not try smaller data) was definitely NOT atomic.

We struggled to find a way to determine when a read returned "torn" data.   What we ended up finding was that the "tearing" was always sequential.   The first part of the read/written value was the latest and the next part was not.

So we used a set of sentinel values.  One DINT at the beginning of any tag we were going to read or write and one at the end.  We would set the first sentinel to a value and then updated the rest of the tag.  Then we would set the last sentinel.  We used monotonically increasing values with a forced wrap for the sentinels.

On a read of a tag like that we compare the sentinel values.  If they are the same then we got a good read.  If they were not, we read again.

```
sentinel X header
<data>
sentinel X footer
```

If the data was "torn" during the transfer we saw:

```
sentinel X header
<data>
sentinel X-1 footer
```

I did a fair amount of testing on this (I created and maintain a C library for communicating with Allen-Bradley PLCs) and I was able to show "tearing" with a simple array of two DINTs.  I did not try arrays of smaller values.

In our experience UDTs were no different from arrays of DINTs.  If the value was larger than a DINT, it could be partially read or written with respect to a program scan.